# Why does cross_val_score in sklearn flip the value of the metric?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, loss-function

I am fitting this model from `sklearn`.

```
LogisticRegressionCV(
        solver="sag", scoring="neg_log_loss", verbose=0, n_jobs=-1, cv=10
    )
```

The fitting results in a `model.score` (on training set) of 0.67 and change. Since there is no way (or I don't know how) to access the results of the cross validation performed as part of the model fitting, I run as separate cross validation on the same model with

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring="neg_log_loss")
```

This returns an array of negative numbers

```
[-0.69517214 -0.69211235 -0.64173978 -0.66429986 -0.77126878 -0.65127196
 -0.66302393 -0.65916281 -0.66893633 -0.67605681]
```

which, if signs were flipped, would seem in a range compatible with the training score.
I've read the discussion in an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439) about cross_val_score flipping the sign of the given scoring function and the solution seemed that `neg_*` metrics were being introduced to make such flipping unnecessary and I am using `neg_log_loss`. The issue talks about `mse` but the arguments seem to apply to `log_loss` as well.  Is there a way to have `cross_val_score` return the same metric as specified in its arguments? Or is this a bug I should file? Or a misunderstanding on my part and sign change is still to be expected from `cross_val_score`?

I hope this is a specific enough question for SO. `Sklearn` devs redirect users to SO for questions that are not clear-cut bug reports or feature reqs.

Adding minimal repro code per request in comments (sklearn v 0.19.1 python 2.7):

```
from numpy.random import randn, seed
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

seed (0)
X = randn(100,2)
y = randn(100)>0
model = LogisticRegressionCV(
    solver="sag", scoring="neg_log_loss", verbose=0, n_jobs=-1, cv=10
)
model.fit(X=X, y=y)
model.score(X,y)

cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring="neg_log_loss")
```

With this code, it doesn't look anymore like it's a simple sign flip for the metric. The outputs are 0.59 for the score and `array([-0.70578452, -0.68773683, -0.68627652, -0.69731349, -0.69198876, -0.70089103, -0.69476663, -0.68279466, -0.70066003, -0.68532253])` for the cross validation score.

Comment: Can you show the complete code and possibly some data which reproduces positive score when `model.score()`? I am not able to duplicate it on scikit-learn inbuilt datasets.

Comment: The complete code is at http://github.com/piccolbo/rightload branch basilica The ML code is in ml.py Sharing the data is more complex and running the code requires access to a web service. I need to think of something more self-contained for a more practical repro.

Comment: The code that generates the positive score is pretty trivial, in ml.py:127 and following lines. model.fit(X,y) followed by model.score(X,y), pretty much. I hope I got your question -- I still owe you some data for a complete repro, of course.

Comment: Got the repro but it requires sharing two pickles with data. Is there a SO preferred way of doing that?

Comment: Replaced repro with one that is self-contained and quick. Doesn't look like a simple sign flip anymore, though.

Comment: Ah.. I should have asked about the scikit-learn version first. You are using 0.19 which returns accuracy (not neg_log_loss) when `model.score()` is called. That has been changed in version 0.20. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: edited after the fruitful comment thread with [Vivek Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3374996/vivek-kumar) and [piccolbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345345/piccolbo).*

#### About LinearRegressionCV `score` method's strange results

You found a bug, which was fixed in version `0.20.0`.

From the [changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-20-0):

> Fix: Fixed a bug in linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV where the score method always computes accuracy, not the metric given by the scoring parameter. [#10998](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10998) by Thomas Fan.

Also, sklearn's 0.19 LogisticRegressionCV [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.score) says:

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> Returns the **mean accuracy** on the given test data and labels.

While from version `0.20.0`, the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.score) are updated with the bugfix:

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> Returns the **score using the scoring option** on the given test data and labels.

---

#### About the negative values returned in `cross_val_score`

`cross_val_score` flips the result value for `error` or `loss` metrics, while it preserves the sign for `score` metrics. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values):

> All scorer objects follow the convention that higher return values are better than lower return values. Thus metrics which measure the distance between the model and the data, like metrics.mean_squared_error, are available as neg_mean_squared_error which return the negated value of the metric.

Comment: I don't understand why I got a negative vote. I reduced the assertivity of my answer, in case that was the problem. I think it adds useful information on the topic, at least.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. LogisticRegressionCV returns [mean accuracy in version 0.19](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV). From version 0.20 upwards, it returns the score for the defined `scoring` param.

Comment: The problem is solved upgrading sklearn. This was suggested in a comment which seems to have disappeared, then in Julian's answer which contains many other things that IMHO are weakly related. If he could simplify it to the point of accuracy vs requested metric as changed in the latest sklearn version, I'd be glad to mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @piccolbo glad to hear it's solved! It was a really tricky scenario. I did some editions to the answer, removing some argumental turnarounds, giving relevant credits, keeping the information on the problem of accuracy (and showing detailed explicit citations on the matter) and also the information about the sign flip for `cross_val_score` (which is not trivial and seems somehow relevant too, at least for the first part of your question before the repro code). Does it look good? Any suggestion?

Comment: Actually, I found the bugfix in the changelog!! It's [LogisticRegressionCV.score doesn't respect scoring, inconsistent with GridSearchCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10998). Adding this to the answer.